# White Area in the TabBar and NavigationBar

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar, tabbar

I have Navigation Bar and Tab Bar in my application. And also white area coming with them. When I checked with View Hierarcy it is exist on the Hosting View Controller.

[On the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKcFL.jpg)
[View Hierarcy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FGtt.png)

MainView

```
struct MainView: View {
@StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            switch viewRouter.currentPage {
            case .game:
                GameView()
            case .news:
                NewsView()
            case .politics:
                PoliticsView()
            case .council:
                CouncilView()
            case .settings:
                SettingsView()
            }
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                TabBarIconView(viewRouter: viewRouter, assignedPage: .game, width: geometry.size.width/5, height: geometry.size.height/28, imageName: "TabBarGame", tabName: "game".localized())
                TabBarIconView(viewRouter: viewRouter, assignedPage: .news, width: geometry.size.width/5, height: geometry.size.height/28, imageName: "TabBarNews", tabName: "news".localized())
                TabBarIconView(viewRouter: viewRouter, assignedPage: .politics, width: geometry.size.width/5, height: geometry.size.height/28, imageName: "TabBarPolitics", tabName: "politics".localized())
                TabBarIconView(viewRouter: viewRouter, assignedPage: .council, width: geometry.size.width/5, height: geometry.size.height/28, imageName: "TabBarCouncil", tabName: "council".localized())
                TabBarIconView(viewRouter: viewRouter, assignedPage: .settings, width: geometry.size.width/5, height: geometry.size.height/28, imageName: "TabBarSettings", tabName: "settings".localized())
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height/8)
            .background(Color.accentColor.opacity(0.07))
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        .navigationBarTitle("Ana Menü")
    }
}
```

GameView

```
struct GameView: View {
var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Image("ProfileRectangleBackground")
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        ProfileSmallInfoView(text: "2021")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 25)
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
                    Spacer()
                    VStack {
                        Image("ProfileImage")
                        HStack {
                            Text("prezident".localized())
                            Text("Hüseyin")
                                .fontWeight(.medium)
                                .font(.system(size: 20))
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.top, -15)
                    Spacer()
                    VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                        ProfileSmallInfoView(text: "1. dönem")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 25)
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
                }
                .frame(width: 338, height: 180)
            }
            
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("ideology".localized())
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("TextColor"))
                .font(.system(size: 18))
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                            .padding(.leading, 10)
                        ChoiceBoxView(choice: "socialism".localized())
                        ChoiceBoxView(choice: "liberalism".localized(), isSelected: false)
                        ChoiceBoxView(choice: "leftist".localized(), isSelected: false)
                        ChoiceBoxView(choice: "rightist".localized(), isSelected: false)
                        ChoiceBoxView(choice: "dictatorship".localized(), isSelected: false)
                        Spacer()
                            .padding(.leading, 10)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("economic_choice".localized())
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("TextColor"))
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                            .padding(.leading, 10)
                        ChoiceBoxView(choice: "capitalism".localized())
                        ChoiceBoxView(choice: "mixed_economy".localized(), isSelected: false)
                        ChoiceBoxView(choice: "socialist_economy".localized(), isSelected: false)
                        Spacer()
                            .padding(.leading, 10)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                print("test")
            }) {
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                        .fill(Color.accentColor)
                        .frame(width: 338, height: 110)
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "play.fill")
                            .resizable(resizingMode: .stretch)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 22)
                        Text("Başlat")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.system(size: 14))
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    
                }
            } //: BUTTON
            .padding(.bottom, 10)
        }
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(
                cornerRadius: 16,
                style: .continuous
            )
                .fill(Color.accentColor.opacity(0.07))
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
                .padding(.bottom, -250)
        )
    .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
    }
}
```

TabBarIconView

```
struct TabBarIconView: View {
@StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter

let assignedPage: Page
let width, height: CGFloat
let imageName, tabName: String

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Image(imageName)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: width, height: height)
            .padding(.top, 10)
        Text(tabName)
            .font(.system(size: 10))
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding(.horizontal, -5)
    .onTapGesture {
        viewRouter.currentPage = assignedPage
    }
}
```

I try to remove white area but I don't know where it is exist in the application.

Comment: Try removing the first `Spacer()` in your `MainView`

Comment: I tried with single and two Spacer's but not worked. @Yrb

Comment: You are going to have to post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We will have to get the code, play with it and see what is wrong.